# Binary clock with Lua, how to remove dots that aren't used?

Tags: lua

I have the following binary clock that I grabbed from this [wiki article](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Binary_Clock_widget) (the one that's for v1.5.*) for the [awesome WM](http://awesome.naquadah.org/):

```
binClock = wibox.widget.base.make_widget()
binClock.radius = 1.5
binClock.shift = 1.8
binClock.farShift = 2
binClock.border = 1
binClock.lineWidth = 1
binClock.colorActive = beautiful.bg_focus 

binClock.fit = function(binClock, width, height)
    local size = math.min(width, height)
    return 6 * 2 * binClock.radius + 5 * binClock.shift + 2 * binClock.farShift + 2 * binClock.border + 2 * binClock.border, size
end

binClock.draw = function(binClock, wibox, cr, width, height)
    local curTime = os.date("*t")

    local column = {}
    table.insert(column, string.format("%04d", binClock:dec_bin(string.sub(string.format("%02d", curTime.hour), 1, 1))))
    table.insert(column, string.format("%04d", binClock:dec_bin(string.sub(string.format("%02d", curTime.hour), 2, 2))))
    table.insert(column, string.format("%04d", binClock:dec_bin(string.sub(string.format("%02d", curTime.min), 1, 1))))
    table.insert(column, string.format("%04d", binClock:dec_bin(string.sub(string.format("%02d", curTime.min), 2, 2))))
    table.insert(column, string.format("%04d", binClock:dec_bin(string.sub(string.format("%02d", curTime.sec), 1, 1))))
    table.insert(column, string.format("%04d", binClock:dec_bin(string.sub(string.format("%02d", curTime.sec), 2, 2))))

    local bigColumn = 0
    for i = 0, 5 do
        if math.floor(i / 2) > bigColumn then
            bigColumn = bigColumn + 1
        end
        for j = 0, 3 do
            if string.sub(column[i + 1], j + 1, j + 1) == "0" then 
                active = false 
            else 
                active = true 
            end 
            binClock:draw_point(cr, bigColumn, i, j, active)
        end
    end
end

binClock.dec_bin = function(binClock, inNum)
    inNum = tonumber(inNum)
    local base, enum, outNum, rem = 2, "01", "", 0
    while inNum > (base - 1) do
        inNum, rem = math.floor(inNum / base), math.fmod(inNum, base)
        outNum = string.sub(enum, rem + 1, rem + 1) .. outNum
    end
    outNum = inNum .. outNum
    return outNum
end

binClock.draw_point = function(binClock, cr, bigColumn, column, row, active)
    cr:arc(binClock.border + column * (2 * binClock.radius + binClock.shift) + bigColumn * binClock.farShift + binClock.radius,
        binClock.border + row * (2 * binClock.radius + binClock.shift) + binClock.radius, 2, 0, 2 * math.pi)
    if active then
        cr:set_source_rgba(0, 0.5, 0, 1)
    else
        cr:set_source_rgba(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
    end
    cr:fill()
end

binClocktimer = timer { timeout = 1 }
binClocktimer:connect_signal("timeout", function() binClock:emit_signal("widget::updated") end)
binClocktimer:start()
```

First, if something isn't by default already in Lua that's because this is to be used in the config file for awesome. :)

OK, so what I need is some guidance actually. I am not very familiar with Lua currently, so some guidance is all I ask so I can learn. :)

OK, so first, this code outputs a normal binary clock, but every column has 4 dots (44,44,44), instead of a 23,34,34 setup for the dots, as it would be in a normal binary clock. What's controlling that in this code? So that I can pay around with it.

Next, what controls the color? Right now it's gray background and quite a dark green, I want to brighten both of those up.

And what controls the smoothing? Right now it's outputting circles, would like to see what it's like for it to output squares instead.

That's all I need help with, if you can point me to the code and some documentation for what I need, that should be more than enough. :)

Also, if somebody would be nice enough to add some comments, that also would be awesome. Don't have to be very detailed comments, but at least to the point where it gives an idea of what each thing does. :)

**EDIT:**

Found what modifies the colors, so figured that out. None of the first variables control if it's a square or circle BTW. :)

Answer (score 1):

The draw_point function draws the dots.

The two loops in the draw function are what create the output and is where the columns come from. To do a 23/34/34 layout you would need to modify the inner loop skip the first X points based on the counter of the outer loop I believe.

Comment: OK. After hours I managed to guess it was those two lines. lol. However after observing this for a couple of minutes I noticed I have no idea how to do what you mean. lol. I would need to know the rest of the code to achieve this no? Perhaps a little tip push of how I would need to modify this? Again, I'm a complete Lua newbie. :)

Comment: Actually, if you could translate what you said into code, that would be perfect. ;)